# Core data not load on iOS device

Tags: ios, core-data, device

I've met a problem with core data.

The simple app is to create documents, and the first view controller will show all the documents I've created, which is store in a core data database.

When I was running the program on the iOS simulator, it works fine. And when I run the app on iOS device when connecting the iPad with mac, it works fine, too.

But when I disconnect the iPad from the Mac, or stop running the program in xCode, the app still can run on my iPad. But all the documents created before are not loaded. I can still create documents and they appears on the view controller correctly. But when I stop the app and launch it again, the bookshelf is still empty... Those documents are not loaded from the core data database.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: So how are you saving the documents? Can you edit your post and show some code? It will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is deployed to iOS 5.1 or newer, then you should be using the "Documents/Application Support" folder, and also marking the documents if you do not want them backed up to iCloud. I am finding I need to create "Application Support" if its not there. This is the code I use:

```
    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *appSupportDir = [self applicationAppSupportDirectory];
    if(![manager fileExistsAtPath:appSupportDir]) {
        __autoreleasing NSError *error;
        BOOL ret = [manager createDirectoryAtPath:appSupportDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        if(!ret) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR app support: %@", error);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

- (NSString *)applicationAppSupportDirectory
{
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```